# Suggested theme hook doesn't get applied

Tags: 8, theming

The custom theme hook (abacus-product.html.twig) I've appended via a hook function doesn't get applied. But it shows up in the suggestions.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * abacus-product.html.twig
   * page--taxonomy--term--5.html.twig
   x page--taxonomy--term--%.html.twig
   * page--taxonomy--term.html.twig
   * page--taxonomy.html.twig
   * page.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/abacus/templates/page--taxonomy--term--%.html.twig' -->
```

abacus-product.html.twig is in the same directory as page--taxonomy--term--%.html.twig

**Edit**
This is the hook function:

```
function abacus_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    $path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    if (0 === strpos($path, '/taxonomy/term/')) {
        $weight = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term')->getWeight();
        if ($weight == 0) {
            $suggestions[] = 'abacus-product';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the hook function you are using to get the file name suggestion.

Comment: I've added the function.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**, after further debugging (see comments):

Using `$suggestions[] = 'page__abacus__product'` and a template called `page--abacus--product.html.twig` works. Theme suggestions should contain double underscores.

Comment: Sorry for not answering.
Sadly changing to 'abacus_product' has not helped.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes I did several times.

Comment: Using `$suggestions[] = 'page__abacus__product'` and a template called `page--abacus--product.html.twig` works for me

Comment: Thank you very much! With the `page__` in front it finally works. It seams that suggestions have to contain 3 parts.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the 
$suggestions[] = 'abacus-product';
is the problem for two reasons.

First it needs to start with the theme hook with two underscores - i.e.
page__abacus-product.

And - this is a subtle error - the '-' in abacus-product should be an underscore.  So the line should be:
$suggestions[] = 'page__abacus_product';

I know that the template will use a hyphen - and the suggestions listed by debug will have hyphens - but unless it is an underscore first the template file will not be used.

Also - not putting page__ at the beginning may result in the wrong twig template variables not being consistent with the variables in the base template.

Answer (score 1):

To get the abacus-product.html.twig template picked up you need to register it with a [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/search/8/hook_theme) implementation first. Unfortunately in this case the theme debug is a bit misleading for you, but the theme debug functionality is not tied into the theme registry so it can't know whether you've registered `abacus_product` or not.

Example code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function abacus_theme() {
  return array(
    'abacus_product' => array(
      'base hook' => 'page',
      'render element' => 'page',
    ),
  );
}
```

However that approach might be a bit unusual depending on your use case. If you're happy with the 'page' prefix, you can just "extend" the `page` theme hook with a suggestion like so (it doesn't need to contain 3 parts as eluded to in the comments):

```
$suggestions[] = 'page__abacus_product';
```

That would allow you to use a template `page--abacus-product.html.twig` without needing to implement `hook_theme()` at all. 
[drupal_find_theme_templates()](https://api.drupal.org/api/search/8/drupal_find_theme_templates) automatically adds templates that are extending existing hooks (suffixed with double underscore) to the theme registry. This means that such templates don't need to be registered separately in a `hook_theme()`, like the above `page--abacus-product.html.twig`, because `page` already exists in the theme registry.

This code in `\Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager::theme()` (right after the suggestion alter hooks are invoked) is where the theme registry is checked.

```
// Check if each suggestion exists in the theme registry, and if so,
// use it instead of the hook that _theme() was called with. For example, a
// function may call _theme('node', ...), but a module can add
// 'node__article' as a suggestion via hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter(),
// enabling a theme to have an alternate template file for article nodes.
foreach (array_reverse($suggestions) as $suggestion) {
  if ($theme_registry->has($suggestion)) {
    $info = $theme_registry->get($suggestion);
    break;
  }
}
```